# The 'Software Updater' does not have enough disk space on /boot drive

Tags: boot

The 'Software Updater' states my computer does not have enough disk space on the /boot drive. It instructed me to free up enough space, but I do not have permission to delete any files. What should I do?

Also, deleting general files (pics, videos, etc.) off my hard drive does not help.

Comment: The solution to this problem has already been answered here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boot partition is full. You will need to remove some old linux image files from that partition to make room. The steps to do this have already been posted in this question here: [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)